# UIColor doesn't work with it's own properties

Tags: objective-c, colors

If I use the color directly, it works. But if i want to save the colour value in rgb and alpha  it doesn't work. It doesn't draw anything.

```
UIColor *aaa = [UIColor grayColor];
float r,g,b,a;

[aaa getRed:&r green:&g blue:&b alpha:&a];
aaa = [UIColor colorWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:a];

CGColorRef col = aaa.CGColor;
```

How can I save my rgb?

Comment: What does not work? Explain better.

Comment: What is your problem? In your code you create a constant gray UIColor object. Then you receive the rgba values of it. R, g and b should have all the same value as they represent some shade of gray. A would be 1.0f. Then you create a new color with the same values and derrive a CGColorRef of this very gray. What do you expect?

Comment: After these lines i draw some lines within CGContext. If I don't change aaa it does draw them, otherwise it does not. And I am asking why doesn't it accept its own properties properly and how can i save my colour with ints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is that `grayColor` is not defined with a colorspace that's compatible with the `getRed:green:blue:alpha:` method.  You can verify this by initializing the `rgba` values to something impossible for a color and noting that they are not changed by the call, which matches the documented return behavior.  Or, replace `grayColor` with something that explicitly includes colors, such as `cyanColor` and the `getRed:green:blue:alpha:` method works.

Here's a bit of code to demonstrate:

```
float r = 5.0,g = 6.0,b = 7.0,a = 8.0, w = 3.0, a2 = 4.0;
UIColor *aaa = [UIColor grayColor];
[aaa getRed:&r green:&g blue:&b alpha:&a];
[aaa getWhite:&w alpha:&a2];
```

(On OS X there are methods for converting between colorspaces but I'm not seeing iOS equivalents.)

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I couldn't locate my problem here because i had some type conversation mistakes.

Answer (score -1):

You have to initialize the floats, otherwise the references &f, &g, &b, &a reference nothing:

```
UIColor *aaa = [UIColor grayColor];
float r = 0.0f, g = 0.0f, b = 0.0f, a = 0.0f;

[aaa getRed:&r green:&g blue:&b alpha:&a];
aaa = [UIColor colorWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:a];

CGColorRef col = aaa.CGColor;
```

Comment: No, there is no need to initialize the values. The values are set when they are redeived using the getRed:greeen:blue:alpha: method.